# How to get a unique comma separated string from a non-unique string in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, unique

i have a php string

```
$select_columms = 'pid, p.title, caption, filepath, filename, encaption, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, ult_puja, p.title, user2, user3';
```

so i had this idea i could get a unique string with this line of code

```
$select_columns = implode(',', array_unique(array_filter(explode(',',$select_columns))));
```

but it doesn't seem to work can you see what i am missing?

*edit:* 
*thanks* for the help my final code is:

```
$select_columns = implode(',', array_filter(array_unique(explode(',', $select_columns))));
```

which outputs `$select_columns = 'pid, p.title, caption, filepath, filename, encaption, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, ult_puja'`

i use the array_filter in case i have input like `', pid,'`

Comment: So you mean you want to remove duplicate values that appear in your comma separated string, and leave the output as a comma separated string?

Comment: exactly @Neddy the logic creating the select statement was causing duplicate fields to be queried

Comment: can anyone tell me why the order of the functions made the difference?

Comment: as @amitchd points out in the comments to my solution, your code won't work if there are spaces between the columns. 'pid , pid , pid' would return pid twice. I amended my solution to take that into account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems fine to me.  2 issues:

1) you've spelt "`columns`" wrong in the variable declaration

2) `array_filter()` is redundant here - it works exactly the same without it.

demo:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $select_columns = 'pid, p.title, caption, filepath, filename, encaption, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, ult_puja, p.title, user2, user3';

php > echo  implode(',', array_unique(explode(',',$select_columns)));
pid, p.title, caption, filepath, filename, encaption, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, ult_puja

php >
```

Comment: thanks but sometime the input might be , pid, p.title, caption, filepath, file so i needed to remove blank enties too

Comment: i un-accepted the answer when i found out that it was the order of the array_filter that made the difference in my code

Comment: @Traveling_Monk: fair enough.  for future reference, most of the confusion could have been avoided if you'd been more explicit than "it doesn't seem to work" :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this out

```
echo implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $select_columms)));
```

**EDIT** As @amitchd  pointed out. Fails hard when not trimmed. Fixed now

And if your string has uneven spacing, you can do this

```
$select_columms = 'pid, p.title, caption, filepath, filename, encaption, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, ult_puja, p.title, user2, user3';
$arr    = explode(',', $select_columms);
array_walk($arr, '_trim');
echo implode(',', array_unique($arr));

function _trim(&$value) {
    $value = trim($value);   
}
```

Comment: Might want to do a array_walk with the trim function on the result of the explode before running the array_unique function :).

Comment: @amitchd, I thought of that, but then I figured that the spaces will get unique'd out anyway and it's not going to affect the output while adding another function to the chain

Comment: @JohnP, $select_columms = 'pid, pid, pid'; and you will have two pids.

Comment: @amitchd sorry! well, that's embarrassing. forgot that , is the delim. I posted a fix. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: what about handling 
$select_columms = ', ,pid, p.title, caption, filepath, filename, encaption, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, ult_puja, p.title, user2, user3';
that is why i used array filter and was why the original code

Comment: @Travelling_Monk, the solution works fine for that case as well. Doesn't it give you the expected output when this string is given? And as @amitchd mentioned, your output is wrong when you have 2 columns with one having a space before/after the column

Answer (score 0):

JohnP's answer should work.  As a personal preference, I'd separate this out to two lines at least.  Three functions on a single line can be hard to read...

Answer (score 0):

Columns was spelt wrong, array_filter was unnecssary and the explode/implode were missing a space after the comma.

```
<?php
$select_columns = 'pid, p.title, caption, filepath, filename, encaption, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, ult_puja, p.title, user2, user3';

$select_columns = implode(', ',array_unique(explode(', ',$select_columns)));

var_dump($select_columns);
?>
```

http://ideone.com/clone/b6dZd

Comment: the columns was actually spellled right in the app, i don't believe the spacing in implode or explode makes a diff...

Comment: @Traveling_Monk Yeah that's true.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $str)));
```